# In kdb, is there an equivalent of left join on multiple columns with inequalities (like a modifiable version of asof joins)?

Tags: sql, kdb

I have an order table in kdb which has order ids, order entry time and order deletion time, as shown below:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id |        entrytime        |       deletetime        |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2020.01.01T00:00:00.000 | 2020.01.01T04:00:00.000 |
|  2 | 2020.01.01T00:00:00.000 | 2020.01.01T03:59:58.000 |
|  3 | 2020.01.01T00:00:00.000 | 2020.01.01T00:00:02.000 |
|... | ...                     | ...                     |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I would like to convert this into view that shows open/active orders every second, as shown below:

```
+-------------------------+---------+
|        datetime         | openids |
+-------------------------+---------+
| 2020.01.01T00:00:00.000 | 1 2 3   |
| 2020.01.01T00:00:01.000 | 1 2 3   |
| 2020.01.01T00:00:02.000 | 1 2     |
| 2020.01.01T00:00:03.000 | 1 2     |
| ...                     | ...     |
| 2020.01.01T03:59:57.000 | 1 2     |
| 2020.01.01T03:59:58.000 | 1       |
| 2020.01.01T03:59:59.000 | 1       |
| 2020.01.01T04:00:00.000 |         |
+-------------------------+---------+
```

What I need is an equivalent of 
`SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN ON datetime >= entrytime and datetime < deletetime` in kdb.

I have tried window joins but with little success.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to do this. Please, see one of them below.
But to start with I would convert times to `timestamp` type, `datetime` is hard to deal with and considered obsolete.

```
t: ([] id: 1 2 3
    ; entrytime: 3#2020.01.01D
    ; deletetime: 2020.01.01D04:00:00 2020.01.01D03:59:58 2020.01.01D00:00:02);
t: update datetime: {x+00:00:01*til `int$1e-9*y-x}'[entrytime;deletetime] from t;
t: ungroup t;
t: select openid: id by datetime from t;
timetable: ([]datetime: {x+00:00:01*til 2+`int$1e-9*y-x} . value exec min datetime
    , max datetime from t);
t: timetable lj t;
t
```

Explanation:

1. Add datetime column to table `t` which keeps track of all times when order is available with with one second step
2. `ungroup` table `t` to get id<->available time mapping
3. group table `t` by available time. This already gives result you are looking for. But there could be gaps for times when no orders were available
4. Fill gaps by joining `timetable`, which has all times in orders' create/delete times range, with table `t`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this without using a join of any sort, and in a single line:

```
q)`datetime xgroup ungroup select id,datetime:entrytime+"v"$til each"j"$deletetime.second-entrytime.second from t
datetime               | id
-----------------------| -----
2020.01.01T00:00:00.000| 1 2 3
2020.01.01T00:00:01.000| 1 2 3
2020.01.01T00:00:02.000| 1 2
2020.01.01T00:00:03.000| 1 2
2020.01.01T00:00:04.000| 1 2
...
```

This will get the time difference between the entrytime and deletetime by taking only the seconds component using `.second`. Then casting this into a long using `"j"$` will get a number which `til each` can be used on. Finally, casting back to a second type using `"v"$` and adding the original entrytime to these lists will create a list of seconds for which each id is active for:

```
q)select id,datetime:entrytime+"v"$til each"j"$deletetime.second-entrytime.second from t
id datetime                                                                  ..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
1  2020.01.01T00:00:00.000 2020.01.01T00:00:01.000 2020.01.01T00:00:02.000 20..
2  2020.01.01T00:00:00.000 2020.01.01T00:00:01.000 2020.01.01T00:00:02.000 20..
3  2020.01.01T00:00:00.000 2020.01.01T00:00:01.000                           ..
```

Finally, using ungroup will ungroup the datetime column, then immediately using xgroup on the datetime column will group the ids that are active for that second.